# Integrate SpreadJS in Oracle APEX

Tags: excel, import, oracle-apex, spreadjs

I am new to Oracle APEX, i am using apex version 21.1.0, i just want to upload excel file with password protected, so i have used Spread JS java script plugin, while i am trying to integrate i am getting this below error which attached in screenshot.

[image]

I have a Oracle APEX form like below:

[image]

I have created one region, and three page items

1. File Upload         type - file
2. Password Input      type - password
3. Button              type - Button

The page properties like below:

[image]

I have added the below code in HTML Header

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs /node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets/styles/gc.spread.sheets.excel2013white.css">
<script src="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets/dist/gc.spread.sheets.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/spread/source/js/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-excelio/dist/gc.spread.excelio.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets-charts/dist/gc.spread.sheets.charts.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/spread/source/js/license.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/spread/source/data/excel_data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var spread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById("append"),  {calcOnDemand: true});
        spread.fromJSON(jsonData);
        var excelIo = new GC.Spread.Excel.IO();
        document.getElementById('B43349412666678933129').onclick = function () {
            var excelFile = document.getElementById("P2_UPLOAD_FILE").files[0];
            var password = document.getElementById('P2_PASSWORD').value;                                                
            // here is excel IO API
            excelIo.open(excelFile, function (json) {
                var workbookObj = json;                  
                    spread.fromJSON(workbookObj);
            }, function (e) {
                // process error
                alert(e.errorMessage);
                if (e.errorCode === 2/*noPassword*/ || e.errorCode === 3 /*invalidPassword*/) {
                    document.getElementById('P2_PASSWORD').onselect = null;
                }
            }, {password: password});
        };            
    };
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div id="append"></div>
 </body>
```

Please correct me if i am wrong or missed something.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am a Technical Engagement Engineer of GrapeCity supporting SpreadJS. I wanted to note that SpreadJS, as of the current version (V14.1.0), it is not tested for or uses APEX software. If you experience any issues please report them to the SpreadJS team here: https://www.grapecity.com/my-account/my-support/

I was able to integrate SpreadJS to an APEX application following these steps:

1. We must first include SpreadJS JS and CSS files. When in the App builder select the root element in the tree under the rendering tab, then on the right pane, scroll down through the properties until you find the **JavaScript** properties section.
2. Under the **JavaScript** properties include SpreadJS’s JS and CSS file urls in the specified areas:
   [image]

Here are the necessary SpreadJS links:

**JS:**

- https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets/dist/gc.spread.sheets.all.min.js
- https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/spread/source/js/FileSaver.js
- https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-excelio/dist/gc.spread.excelio.min.js
- https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets-charts/dist/gc.spread.sheets.charts.min.js

**CSS:**

- https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/en/purejs/node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets/styles/gc.spread.sheets.excel2013white.css

3. Next, create a region named SpreadJS
4. Within the SpreadJS region, right click, and create the following:

- A File Browser type named **P1_UPLOAD_FILE**
- A Password type item named **P1_PASSWORD**
- A Button titled Import with the Static ID being **import**, the Static ID property can be found under the **Advanced properties**:

[image]

- A Sub Region named ss with Static ID set to **ss**:
  [image]

5. Next, besure to select the root element of the tree and navigate to the JavaScript section in the right pane
6. Initialize SpreadJS under the **Function and global variable declaration** section. Here is a code snippet I used that will display spreadjs to the ss sub region and trigger the importing using the button, file browser, and password:

```js
GC.Spread.Sheets.LicenseKey = "sjs-distribution key";
window.onload = function () {
    var spread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById("ss"), {calcOnDemand: true});
    var excelIo = new GC.Spread.Excel.IO();
      document.getElementById('import').onclick = function () {
        var excelFile = document.getElementById("P1_UPLOAD_FILE").files[0];
        var password = document.getElementById('P1_PASSWORD').value;
        // here is excel IO API
        excelIo.open(excelFile, function (json) {
            var workbookObj = json;
                spread.fromJSON(workbookObj);
            }
        , function (e) {
            // process error
            alert(e.errorMessage);
            if (e.errorCode === 2/*noPassword*/ || e.errorCode === 3 /*invalidPassword*/) {
                document.getElementById('password').onselect = null;
            }
        }, {password: password});
    };
}
```

As I shared previously in my post, please keep in mind that SpreadJS has not been tested within an APEX application so there may be some unexpected behavior. Please reach out to SpreadJS's team if you encounter any issues!

Comment: Hi Team GrapeCity,

I have followed the above steps and trying to upload excel file but i am facing an issues with validation, the validation  error i am getting is "Incorrect file format", may i know which format should work?, but here the objective is we need to upload only Excel Files